# call wp_insert_user in custom class doesnt work

Tags: functions, users, user-registration

im creating a custom class to manage users in wordpress and chamilo but this is not the point.

Class looks like this:

```
class Platform
{
    private $security_key = '..';
    private $secret_key;
    private $firstname;
    private $lastname;
    private $status;
    private $email;
    private $login;
    private $password;
    private $encrypt_method = "md5";
    private $original_user_id_name = "uid";
    private $original_user_id_value;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $arguments = func_get_args();
        if(!empty($arguments))
            foreach($arguments[0] as $key => $property)
            if(property_exists($this, $key))
            $this->{$key} = $property;
    }
    /*
     * Do autoryzacji z chamilo potrzeba IP clienta + auth_code.
    * Z tych danych jest tworzyony API_KEY potrzeby podczas komunikacje z platformą.
    * Funkcje sprawdzają akutalne IP oraz auth_code platformy i generują API_KEY
    */
    public function check_client_ip()
    {
        $ip = trim($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);
        if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'])) {
            list($ip1,$ip2) = split(',',$_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR']);
            $ip = trim($ip1);
        }
        return $ip;
    }
    public function generate_secret_key()
    {
        $ip_address = $this->check_client_ip();
        $secret_key = sha1($ip_address.$this->security_key);
        return $secret_key;
    }
    /*
     * Dodawanie użytkownika w Chamilo
    */
    public function add_user_to_chamilo()
    {
        $params = array(
                'firstname'                 => $this->firstname,
                'lastname'                  => $this->lastname,
                'status'                    => '5', // 5 STUDENT - 1 TEACHER - zawsze ustawiamy na studenta - konta administracyjne będziemy tworzyć ręcznie
                'email'                     => $this->email,
                'loginname'                 => $this->login,
                'password'                  => $this->password, // encrypted using sha1
                'encrypt_method'            => 'md5',
                'language'                  => 'Polish',
                'official_code'             => '',
                'phone'                     => '',
                'expiration_date'           => '0000-00-00',
                'original_user_id_name'     => 'uid', // the extra user field that will be automatically created in the user profile see: main/admin/user_fields.php
                'original_user_id_value'    => $this->wp_user_id, // third party user id
                'secret_key'                => $this->generate_secret_key(),
        );
        echo "<pre>";
        print_r($params);
        echo "</pre>";

        //$client = new SoapClient('http://....pl/registration.soap.php?wsdl');
        //$response = $client->WSCreateUserPasswordCrypted($params);
    }
    /*
     * Dodawanie użytkownika w Wordpress
    */
    public function add_user_to_wordpress()
    {
        $params = array(
                'ID'                        => '',
                'first_name'                => $this->firstname,
                'last_name'                 => $this->lastname,
                'user_email'                => $this->email,
                'user_login'                => $this->login,
                'user_pass'                 => $this->password,
                'role'                      => 'subscriber'
        );
        echo "<pre>";
        print_r($params);
        echo "</pre>";
        wp_insert_user($params);
    }
}
```

This is how i initialize the class in wordpress page (page-adduser.php)

```
$p = new Platform(array(
        'firstname'                 => 'John',
        'lastname'                  => 'Doe',
        'email'                     => 'test@example.com',
        'login'                     => 'test',
        'password'                  => 'somepass'

        )
);
```

Then i run public function add_user_to_wordpress

```
$p-> add_user_to_wordpress();
```

So it prints data from $params array but it seems this is not running wp_insert user.

Data printed:

```
Array
(
    [ID] => 
    [first_name] => John
    [last_name] => Doe
    [user_email] => test@example.com
    [user_login] => test
    [user_pass] => somepass
    [role] => subscriber
)
```

Can You tell me how to runn wordpress functions inside my custom class.

BTW class i loaded to function.php file in theme as a first line.

Comment: It seems that wp_insert_post is working just not accepting values like $this->firstname etc.

Comment: please edit the question to add info instead of commenting on it.

Comment: Do you have [debugging enabled](http://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress)? How and where do you use this class?

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the debugging advice from @s_ha_dum, you could try to catch the possible `WP_Error` thrown by `wp_insert_user()`:

```
$user_id = wp_insert_user($params);

if ( is_wp_error( $user_id ) )
{
   echo $user_id->get_error_message();
}
else
{
    printf( 'User created with user_id = %d', $user_id );
}
```

Maybe the user already exists?

You could also use `email_exists()` and `username_exists()` to check.